# CSS visibility rule for Tooltip doesn't work

Tags: html, css, visibility, display

display: none; vs visibility: hidden;

I know that "display: none;" will not take space and "visibility: hidden;" will take space when hidden.

Then why is this tooltip defined by "visibility: hidden;" is NOT taking space? It is acting like "display: none;"

In short, the tooltip should not overlap the text beneath it, right?

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <div class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</div>
</div>

<p>Note that the tooltip is overlapping the text beneath it. The text should appear below the tooltip position, right?</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this part of  code.  and you will see the difference

```
/* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
```